# Ajax is not working in the Pagination

Tags: ajax, cakephp, pagination

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. In one of my projects, I want to create `Ajax Pagination`. For that, I tried this :

In my `AppController.php` :

```
public $helpers=array('Js','Paginator');
public $components=array('RequestHandler');
```

In my `Cntrl1Controller.php` :

```
public $paginate=array(
                    'Model1'=>array(
                              'limit'=>10,
                              'order'=>array('Model1.field1 DESC')
                     )
)

public function index(){
  $this->paginate['Model1']['conditions']=array('Model1.field1'=>[value]);
  $data1=$this->paginate('Model1');
  $this->set('data1',$data1);
}
```

In my `Cntrl2Controller.php` :

```
public $paginate=array(
                    'Model2'=>array(
                              'limit'=>10,
                              'order'=>array('Model2.field1 DESC')
                     )
)

public function index(){
  $this->paginate['Model2']['conditions']=array('Model2.field1'=>[value]);
  $data2=$this->paginate('Model2');
  $this->set('data2',$data2);
}
```

In my `View` file(s) (both are `index.ctp`) :

```
<ul class="pagination">
<?php
    echo "<li>".$this->Paginator->prev('Prev')."</li>".$this->Paginator->numbers(array('tag'=>'li','currentClass'=>'active','currentTag'=>'a','separator'=>null))."<li>".$this->Paginator->next('Next')."</li>";
?>
</ul>
```

In my `default layout` :

```
<head>
<?php
    $this->Paginator->options(
                           array(
                             'update'=>'#content','evalScripts'=>true,
                             'before'=>$this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer'=>false)),
                             'complete'=>$this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer'=>false))
                           )
    );
?>
</head>
<body>
.
.
.
<?php
   echo $this->Html->image('indicator.gif',array('id'=>'busy-indicator'));
?>
.
.
.
<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();?>
</body>
```

Now, my problem is, pagination is working fine, all data are returned successfully. But, its not `AJAX Pagination`, I mean, while I navigate through the pages, the entire page reloads, not just the `content <div>`. But, I want that only that `div` will be reloaded, nothing else.

So, what do you guys think ? What is the problem here ? What should I do ?

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please check your code in the Controller Action. It should use the paginate() function instead of find(). http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I've just edited my question, cz my problem has changed. Can you please have a look at it again ? @VikashPathak

Comment: If you have a javascript problem, you need to *say what it is* - open the console, look for js errors and put them in the question. None of the code in the question appears to be relevant.

Comment: Well, frankly speaking, I can't use console yet. I am a new Web Developer. I saw this code in the CakePHP documentation to implement the AJAX Pagination, and I tried it, but it's not working, that's why I pasted the code here and asked for help. Can you please give me any suggestion, what it could be ? Thanks :) @AD7six

Comment: If you can't use your browser yet - I suggest learning to do so, right now =). You aren't going to get far fixing javascript problems if you're unable to see them. e.g. [here's the docs for chrome's](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index)

Comment: Hmm, I got it. Thanks. But, don't you have any idea what is the wrong here ? :) @AD7six

Comment: Ok, I've just seen the console, it doesn't give any error. @AD7six

Answer (score 1):

I think, you've forgot to add the buffer code at the bottom of the page.

**echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); // Write cached scripts**

and also check your browser console there may have some js issue.

Comment: No, I have this code in my layout page. Even the "loading" gif image does not also appear. I've just updated my question with that line of code. Can you please have a look at it again. Thanks :) @VikashPathak

Comment: In chrome just press F12 for console window. and go to the console tab.. here you can view all of the js issue and response.

Comment: also that would be fine fine if you specify the JS helper with engine like: public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));

Comment: Hmm, trying @VikashPathak

Comment: Nope, not working, same result. Did you notice that, my pagination is working, but "Ajax Pagination" is not ? @VikashPathak

Comment: it may caused due to some js issue. please check at your console.